# error: x86 'interrupt' attribute only applies to functions that have only a pointer parameter optionally followed by an integer parameter

Tags: c, gcc, interrupt

I'm trying to compile in VS Code but error appears for this line of code:

```
void interrupt_handler_function(void) __attribute__ ((interrupt("FIQ")));
```

error:

> error: x86 'interrupt' attribute only applies to functions that have only a pointer parameter optionally followed by an integer parameter

Compiler is: GCC 9.4.0 x86_64-linux-gnu

Am I missing something in the interrupt declaration? Any input is much appreciated!

Tried solution in this link: [clang-check using arm as a target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142013/clang-check-using-arm-as-a-target) but did not work

Comment: Well, you don't have a pointer parameter ...

Comment: The other question is about trying to compile for ARM, not x86.

Comment: x86 compiler and ARM target - install correct toolchain

Comment: @0___________, I changed the compiler with the correct one, but the error still persits.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, isn't it that interrupt hander functions should have no parameters? Why is it looking for a pointer parameter?

Comment: @rammmmm_: that probably depends on the platform, so there's an incompatibility, it seems, between the code and the targeted platform.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I am using an ARM compiler now for an ARM target device. This is with Lauterbach Trace32 as debugger. Can you suggest some leads for this issue? Would highly appreciate it.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I tried putting dummy pointer in the parameter like `void interrupt_handler_function(int *ptr) __attribute__ ((interrupt("FIQ")));` and the error was gone. However, I am not really convinced I should be passing a parameter to an interrupt handler function.